# Как логичнее всего реализовать соединение алгоритмов django и SQL?

Tags: python, django, sqlite3

SQLite очень не любит, когда в объект базы стучатся из разных потоков. В то время как Django использует многопоточность. У меня никак не получается обойтись без ручной блокировки исполнения, если уже происходит редактирование, даже если коммиты не взаимосвязаны никак. Есть идея - костыль, когда будет локальный TCP-брокер, которому будут приходить SQL-команды, он будет их обрабатывать и возвращать результат. Но это довольно затратно по ресурсам. Может кто-нибудь подскажет как это можно реализовать?

Comment: SQLite сам автоматически блокирует всё что надо, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: (разве что может понадобиться увеличить timeout, но там и так по умолчанию стоит 5 секунд, чего должно хватать для большинства задач)

Comment: Кстати, утверждение «Django использует многопоточность» является неверным — вы сами в настройках своего WSGI/ASGI-сервера настраиваете, сколько процессов и/или потоков запускать. Можно вместо потоков использовать процессы, и тогда точно никаких проблем быть не должно (я использую SQLite+Django в продакшене много лет и никаких проблем не испытываю)

Comment: @andreymal, я получаю ошибку обращения к одному объекту коннекта БД из других потоков. Логично рассудить что раз ошибка происходит в функции обработки страницы, то проблема в создании потоков и обращения у них в Джанго?

Comment: Ну тогда просто отключите создание потоков, например?

Comment: Проблем точно не будет?